How can i solve Ubuntu 24.04 freeze requiring hard reset on video calls and other harwdare acclerated video apps
I have recently bought a ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 12 and installed ubuntu 24.04.
Unfortunately i experience crashes. Those crashes seem to relate to applications using display stuff for hardware acceleration:
I noticed the freeze mostly seems to happens doing videoconferencing, screen sharing or using other applications that use hardware acceleration.
I also experience screen flickering when an external screen is positioned above the laptop screen (not left or right). The screen flickering when connecting the screen via USB is extreme and causes a crash within a minute.
Using X11 seems to avoid the problem but does not work for me: some application do not work with X11 and the battery life is reduced a lot.
Specifically chromium causes a crash with in a minute doing video conferencing while firefox seems to handle video without a problem. The work-around i found for video conferencing for chromium is to disable the hardware acceleration. This seems to work most of the time for the video calls using a browser.
However, that only works for applications you can control using hardware acceleration or not. Other applications will still cause a crash requiring a hard-reset using the off button to be pressed for >10seconds.
Disabling wayland also seems avoid the crash. That is not a solution for me: some apps i use only work with wayland.
I hope this can be resolved soon because it makes working with linux unusable.

I also face random freezes and crashes on an older Thinkpad Notebook. I upügraded from 22.04 to 24.04 and in randomly crashes. Symptoms: Cannot move mouse to second monitor, alt-Tab Overlay is shown and unable to close it. No input possible. So your are not the only one facing problems with Ubuntu 24.04. Guess we have to wait until a new kernel comes.

As a solution I tried fedora and it seems to be a much smoother experience than ubuntu: much more stable (even before the current crashes on my new computer is experienced regular crashes on my old computer requirnig at least 1 reboot a day).
It is a bit getting used to the the fedora way of doing things but overall i'm pretty happy with it, so for me: goodby ubuntu (after >15 years!)

This is not an answer to the problem itself.
